# Applescript - rsync to NAS Drive

Tags: shell, applescript, rsync, nas

I've checked out a few questions but none have helped so far.

I have an AppleScript backing up my RAW files from one HDD to another, and I'd like to include a NAS drive in that process.  I'm using `rysnc` to copy the files, but I'm having trouble referencing the NAS Drive in my `rsync` command.

I have a line of code referencing the NAS Drive as a test which is working:
`do shell script "open 'smb://NASDrive/Matt RAW Backup/Backups'"`

However, the following line of code isn't working:
`do shell script "rsync -a '/Users/Matt/Desktop/Test Folder/' '/Volumes/NASDrive/Matt RAW Backup/Backups' --delete"`

('NASDrive' is the name of the NAS Drive, and 'Matt RAW Backup' is the share name)

I get the following error in the 'Result' bar:

> error "ssh: Could not resolve hostname smb: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
>   rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
>   rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]" number 255

Does anyone know why the `rsync` command is failing, but the `open` command with the same reference to the folder is working?

Comment: You are missing the leading slash on `rsync -a '/Users...`

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell, I've fixed that.  Unfortunately it's still failing.  I've updated the question.

Comment: What happens if you type the `rsync` command straight into Terminal?

Comment: Same error @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a timing issue.

I recommend to use the AppleScript `mount volume` command and wait until the disk appears in `/Volumes`

You need to replace `server.local` with the server name of your NAS.

```
set diskName to "NASDrive"
try
    mount volume "smb://server.local/" & diskName
    repeat until diskName is in (do shell script "ls /Volumes")
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    do shell script "rsync -a '/Users/Matt/Desktop/Test Folder/' '/Volumes/NASDrive/Matt RAW Backup/Backups' --delete"
on error e
    display dialog "An error occurred: " & e
end try
```